# JSONP callback method is not defined

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, greasemonkey, jsonp

I'm trying to get a jsonp callback working using jquery within a greasemonkey script. Here's my jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mydomain.com/MyWebService?callback=?",
    data: { authkey: "temphash" },
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

in my webservice (asp.net) I'm returning the response with a content type of `application/javascript`. The response the server is actually sending back is:

```
jsonp1276109314602({"message":"I'm getting tired of this not working"})
```

The `jsonp1276109314602` method name is being randomly generated by jquery, and I'm grabbing it with `Request.QueryString["callback"]`

However my success function is never called and the firebug console gives me an error saying `jsonp1276109314602 is not defined`.

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE**
I'm making this call from a greasemonkey script on a craigslist page. It's a cross-domain request, but I can see the request is actually making it to the server and returning a good response, but for whatever reason the registered callback that jquery creates appears to not exist when the response comes back. It works fine if I run the script in the firebug console from the craigslist page, but not when it's run from the greasemonkey script.

Comment: Are you embedding jQuery in the GreaseMonkey script or loading it separately?

Comment: ... Or, is jQuery already available on the page that you're enhancing?

Comment: I've got it loaded in via the greasemonkey script

Comment: you can solve this problem using jsonp.Please follow the link below.
This site also contains demo code. [http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/web-development/javascript/jsonp-example/](http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/web-development/javascript/jsonp-example/) Hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you have to do some extra monkeying around (pun intended) to get it to work inside a greasemonkey script.

The long answer can be found here: [jQuery.getJSON inside a greasemonkey user script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647519/jquery-getjson-inside-a-greasemonkey-user-script).

The short answer is to ditch the JSONP approach and include this in your script:

```
// @require http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i290-4/f09/resources/gm_jq_xhr.js
```

Not sure I understand it all, but nonetheless it works like a champ and I'm able to make cross domain requests from my script.

Comment: If you're interested in how the `gm_jq_xhr.js` script works, you can read [an explanation](http://ryangreenberg.com/archives/2010/03/greasemonkey_jquery.php) I wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Have you already tried:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mydomain.com/MyWebService",
    data: { authkey: "temphash" },
    type: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Will add an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback.

I haven't examined jQuery's source code but it's possible that the callback function isn't created unless you specify jsonp for the dataType option.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're supposed to use 'jsonpCallbackString' instead of 'success'.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/